# Reverse shell working with kali 2016, but not kali 2019.2, using Metasploit ms08_067_netapi

Tags: penetration-test, firewalls, metasploit, kali-linux

I have an unpatched Windows XP Home VM, a Kali 2019.2 VM and an old Kali 2016 VM. Using Metasploit's `ms08_067_netapi` module, I'm able to successfully get a reverse shell but only on the old Kali VM.

I'm trying to get the same reverse shell on Kali 2019.2, but it is not working. However, I've been able to get a meterpreter bind shell running from the Win XP VM to the 2019.2 VM using the same exploit.

I have done the following with IPTABLES to completely clear everything:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

But I still can't catch the reverse shell. Metasploit reports:

```
[ * ] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

Lastly, I have been able to catch a reverse shell from the Windows XP machine to the 2019.2 VM by creating a `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` executable file using `msfvenom` and running it on the target Win XP machine (and catching it on the 2019.2 Kali VM using `multi/handler`), but I still cannot get a reverse shell from Metasploit's `ms08_067_netapi` module.

Any insight on this bug would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you ```set VERBOSE true```  in Metasploit and run MS08-67 again?

Comment: The same thing, started handler on 4444,auto detecting the target, fingerprint Win XP SP 0/1 English, targeting Windows XP SP0/SP1 universal, attempting vulnerability, exploit completed no session created. It's pretty much what the 2016 box's msf says, minus the stager and meterpreter shell.

Comment: Are you utilizing the same payloads? Maybe try altering that to see if any one payload works. It's possible they have changed between MSF versions.

Comment: As mentioned above windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp is the one I'm trying to get to work on the 2019.2 box, and it works on the 2016 box. On the 2019.2 box I am able to successfully use windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp

Comment: Just found that generic/shell_reverse_tcp works

Comment: Awesome, glad you got a resolution. You should be able to upgrade to Meterpreter from the stageless payload by creating a new EXE, hosting it with something like ```python-impacket``` and executing it on the machine with a new multi/handler.

Comment: Bro read my post carefully. I’ve had the payload fine using exe and multi/handler from the beginning. What isn’t working is launching meterpreter on the target from ms08_067_netapi